# Integrate CPLEX with a Java application

Tags: java, cplex

We are developing an application that will use CPLEX to solve an industrial problem. A mathematical model (`mod` file) has been developed. We would like to use this model directly instead of re-transcribing with CPLEX Java API.

In our architecture, we have an application dedicated to retrieving business data and creating suitable `dat` files. The original model and these data files should be sent to a CPLEX instance installed on a separate machine.

The problem is that OPL Java APIs which allow to load and run `mod` files do not provide any API to use a remote CPLEX instance. On the other hand, the CPLEX Java APIs that allow using a remote instance cannot load `mod` files.

Is there any **direct** way to use CPLEX/OPL Java APIs? I have consulted the following resources to no avail:

- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/my-notes-ibm-decision-optimization-scheduling-application-chew/ This one mentions some attractive architectures, but they seem overkill.
- [https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~diam/ro/online/cplex/cplex1271/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/parallel_optim/distribMIP/01_distributed_mip_title_synopsis.html](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ediam/ro/online/cplex/cplex1271/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/parallel_optim/distribMIP/01_distributed_mip_title_synopsis.html) This one seems interesting, though does it require a CPLEX installation on the host (master) machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at github [DOforWMLwithJava](https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/DOforWMLwithJava) and then you call OPL CPLEX models in IBM cloud or in a CloudPak for Data instance.

You can try [oplrunwml](https://medium.com/@alexfleischer-84755/command-line-call-opl-cplex-model-in-watson-machine-learning-518aba1be0b4) through an external call from java

Or you can rely on [Decision Optimization Centre](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/decision-optimization-center) Optimization Server

Comment: Thank you for your response. Due to the internet limitation, the first two options are not possible. I will look to the third one in this link https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/doc/4.0.2?topic=customization-cplex-integration